# Pegar retorno do angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs

Estou utilizando o [angular file upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload), ele funciona muito bem, mas eu preciso do retorno que o servidor me disponibiliza. Estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
  $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
    alias: 'image',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Client-ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    },
    autoUpload: true,
  });
```

A resposta:

```
{"data":{"id":"sK1PnoE","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1454191817,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":400,"height":400,"size":8981,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":0,"comment_preview":null,"deletehash":"LLLGwJ7PdzYsord","name":"","link":"http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/sK1PnoE.png"},"success":true,"status":200}
```

Editado ---

Não estou conseguindo acessar os métodos de CallBacks, tentei das seguintes formas:

```
$scope.uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status,headers) {
      console.log(response);
  };

  $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    //xxxxx
  }).onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status,headers) {
    console.log(response);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dados de resposta do `fileUploader` são recebidos dentro de funções do próprio plugin, seja para sucesso, erro, progresso e outros métodos.

Veja as funções de `callback` desta pagina: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API

Exemplo:

```
$scope.uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status,headers) {
    //sua função aqui...
};
```

Então basta você fazer a verificação do `response` ou `status`, por exemplo, para verificar. Como existe um `callback` para cada etapa, para identificar um erro, você deve utilizar o `callback` `onErrorItem`, para progresso use `onProgressItem`, e assim por diante.

Comment: Atualize o post, de uma olhada. Agradeço pela resposta!

Comment: IO que o console mostra @SCOFIELD ?? E o que voce precisa pegar de informacao? Somente o status se deu certo ou nao?

Comment: Na verdade deu certo :v Eu estava tentando acessar o método do $scope antes de defini-lo (Genius). Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Haha não por isso. =D